# Cannot add WebPart to master page using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I've built a WebPart for a SharePoint 2010 site. I need to add it to one of its master pages (using SharePoint Designer), and when I select it from the WebParts menu I click it but I don't see it added on the design page...

Could you please tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Brian

Comment: Same issue here, do you have the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the Web parts get added to Pages (in a Web Part Zone) not the master page. You can force this by entering Advanced Edit mode in SPD and add a Web Part Zone & Web Part but it is not the way in which Master Pages were intended to be used.